# multiple users of one user account

Tags: windows-7

I use WinCC program for monitoring issues.
We work in shifts from home using Remote Desctop on Windows 7 Pro.
Because the program should be active non-stop i cant't logoff, I need some software that can
authenticate each colleague and record the time of logon/logoff but without changing the user.

I think of some lock your screen software but where you can change accounts on a single user account.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

WinCC runs on Windows 7 machine at the office.
4 people connect remotely in shifts.
The problem is that the program shouldn't be stopped so we can't change users.
I need to audit who connected remotely.
In event viewer I can track different users log on, but in this case we cannot change users.

I hope it's clearer now....

Comment: It's unclear to me how you're set up. Could you make a little diagram to present which computer is shared, where is the remote desktop running and where is it connected? You can use [AsciiFlow](http://asciiflow.com/) or just link to an image, we'll embed it in your question.